# Retrieving data submitted with Yii's CActiveForm

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to retrieve the data from a form created using a widget for CActiveForm.  However, when I click on the submit button, no data is written to targeted Url.  How do I obtain the submitted form data?

```
<p>Please list the ages of the members of your household:</p>

<div class="form offset3">
    <?php
    $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'survey',
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('//survey_resp'),
        'clientOptions' => array(
        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        ),
        'htmlOptions' => array(
        'class' => 'form-horizontal',
        ),
));
?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'age_1'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'age_1'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'age_1'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'age_2'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'age_2'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'age_2'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row rememberMe">
        <?php echo $form->checkBox($model, 'resp_re'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->Label($model, 'resp_re'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model, 'resp_re'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('submit'); ?>
    </div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Does "survey_resp" is your controller or your action ? If it's a action, then you should put the proper url for the form's action.
example:

```
 'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('/you_controller_name/your_action_name'),
```

ps: Remember, if you put "//" in a createUrl, it will generate an url to a basePath or module.
See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail
and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#action-detail